# Place if statement in echo

Tags: php

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = ".toFraction($slope)."x + $b"."$$";
```

However, I want to add an if statement that checks if the number is a decimal to run the function "toFraction". And if it's not a fraction, I want it just to echo the $slope variable without the function. In other words, something like this:

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = ".if(strpos($number,".") !== false){toFraction($slope)}else{$slope}."x + $b"."$$";
```

However, I'm not sure if this is even possible, or if it is, what is the proper way of accomplishing it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: No, it's not possible. Statements can't be part of expressions (string concatenation). A feasible alternative here might be the "ternary operator".

Comment: it is not echo but string you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong you can use an inline if with `?` and `:`:

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = ".(strpos($number,".") !== false ? toFraction($slope) : $slope) . "x + $b"."$$";
```

or try this syntax:

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = ";
if(strpos($number,".") !== false) {
    echo toFraction($slope)
} else {
    echo $slope;
}
echo "x + $b"."$$";
```

The syntax pattern for inline ifs looks like this: `(`*condition*`?`*true path*`:`*false path*`)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = ".((strpos($number,".") !== false) ? toFraction($slope): $slope)."x + $b"."$$";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = " . ((strpos($number,".") !== false ? toFraction($slope) : $slope) . "x + $b" . "$$");
```

Use [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Slope intercept form: $$"."y = ";
if(strpos($number,".") !== false) echo toFraction($slope); else echo $slope;
echo "x + $b"."$$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember 2 simple rules:

1. Try to write vertically, not horizontally. Long statements are either unreadable and obscure.
2. Ternary operator is ugly.

so

```
if (strpos($number,".") !== false) {
    $slope = toFraction($slope);
}
echo 'Slope intercept form: $$y = '.$slope.'x + '.$b.'$$';
```